# How can I prevent certain element to get displayed in Google search excerpt?

Tags: search, seo, google-search

Currently Google displays elements in the result excerpts that belongs to the functional part of the site. Is there a way to exclude these elements to get crawled/displayed in google?

[image]

Like eEdit, eDelete, etc in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Update on my particular situation here: I just found out that the frontend code has been generated in a way where the title and the description meta was identical.
Google is smart enough to expect that if a copy is already displayed in the title of the search result there's no reason to add in to the excerpt as well, instead looks for content - believed to be valuable - from the actual page.

**Lessons learned:**

- there's no way to hide elements from google but keep it visible for your users
- if you'd like to have control over the content displayed in google searches, avoid using the same copy in your title and description

Answer (score -1):

To exclude the pages from Google's index, [block them using the Robots.txt file](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?hl=en) or if it is just the content then use the "rel="nofollow" tag.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Sukh Kaur, but I try to hide certain elements not the whole page.